# Android Beacon Library - Beacon's discovery and disappear time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

In the monitoring activity (where my layout is I have two textviews in one of them discoverTime will be stored and another disappearTime will be stored).

```
    public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity  {
    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    TextView discoverTime;
    TextView disappearTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring);
        verifyBluetooth();
        logToDisplay("Application just launched");

        discoverTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.discoverTime);
        disappearTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.disappearTime);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Android M Permission check
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @TargetApi(23)
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to change textview information when a beacon is found out or disappeared so in the `didEnterRegion` and in `didExitRegion` I set the textview texts.

```
@Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

            // The very first time since boot that we detect an beacon, we launch the
            // MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest
            // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has
            // already manually launched the app.

            //this.startActivity(intent);

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
            String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            monitoringActivity.discoverTime.setText(date);


            haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
        } else {
            if (monitoringActivity != null) {
                // If the Monitoring Activity is visible, we log info about the beacons we have
                // seen on its display
                monitoringActivity.logToDisplay("I see a beacon again" );
            } else {
                // If we have already seen beacons before, but the monitoring activity is not in
                // the foreground, we send a notification to the user on subsequent detections.
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");
                sendNotification();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            monitoringActivity.logToDisplay("I no longer see a beacon.");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        monitoringActivity.disappearTime.setText(date);
    }
```

I tested going out of my Beacon coverage's area but it didn't work.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that you see the entry message but not the exit message?  Do you see log lines from the exit callback?

Comment: when I tried to change textviews in the BeaconReferenceApplication class the app stopped to run... I could check the log because I had to move around so smartphone was not connected to the PC.,.. can I check log messages even when smartphone is not connected with the PC?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are using the Android Beacon Library I assume you mean altbeacon which isn't a Google library - it's a 3rd party library. In your code, I can't see any code to define what beacon you are looking for and set up a region. I think you need to be calling into the BeaconManager to set up a Region. Also, you might be better off using the [Android Bluetooth APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) directly.

Comment: Thanks you are right Android Beacon Library is the name of library but isn't from Google... writing using Android Bluetooth APIs directly would be nice but too much work isn't it? I think I will keep writing the program using Alt Beacon Library as there are functions already written (didEnterRegion, didExitRegion).